# Can we change the name of this closure reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I feel that the close reason for "Questions regarding future unannounced events" should apply to ***All*** future events.

A typical question that is closed under this is: "Is 'My little sister can't be this potato' getting a second season?'

If you don't know the series, **you can't 100% confidently close this question** - Maybe a season 2 was announced and you didn't know about it.

If you know the series you can close it or leave it open with confidence, because you likely have been keeping up with news on this topic. **If you come to the question late however, and it is already closed** - you could argue that *It has been announced* and therefore vote to reopen the question.

Having announced questions on-topic is inconsistent and also prone to becoming redundant over time. Can we apply the rule to **all future events?**

Comment: The problem you describe stays the same. When the new season came out, the "new" reason is just as inconsistent and redundant as the old one. You're exchanging one Problem for another

Comment: this is true, perhaps 'news events' or something similar is needed as a closure reason. I'll think about it some more

Comment: "If you come to the question late however, and it is already closed - you could argue that It has been announced and therefore vote to reopen the question." I don't see this as a problem. If it didn't have an answer/was off topic, it then has one/is on topic. We have one more answered question, and that's great. Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: In general future events are subject to change, so questions can be accepted, but turn out to be wrong. And how many irregular users will update their answers?

Comment: As has been said before, answers will mostly be copy pasting of news sites. And this content is best left to them

Comment: Stack Overflow has a somewhat similar problem to "future events are subject to change": they have answers that were accurate when first written, but currently refer to outdated versions of particular technologies, e.g. Clojure answers that recommend SLIME instead of Cider or cover the installation headaches from before Leiningen. SO seems to just leave it up to the community to make sure answers are up to date.