# Should we be closing image-only id requests differently?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

Most of the time I see image-only id-requests be closed as duplicate of the reverse search question.

However, reviewers need to (should) be verifying themselves that it is in fact a duplicate. I feel like people just assume the initial close vote is correct (and it's been mentioned on chat that this attitude seems to exist)

Should we change our approach to these as 'too little detail to be answered' first and duplicate later?

**Pros:**

- Faster review time (less wasted time for x number of close votes)
- Less chance of incorrect *go with the flow* closures, misleading users
- Less rule complexity (as reverse searching is in the guidelines)

**Cons:**

- Potential for an asker to edit many times, and still be reverse-searchable, wasting their time.
- may be reopened, but searchable because reopen voters haven't checked

What do you think? Is this a worthwhile closure attitude change?

Comment: My general rule of thumb is: Right click the image, *Search Google for this image*, if I can find the answer without scrolling, I close as a duplicate.

Comment: "Should we change our approach to these as 'too little detail to be answered' first and duplicate later?" − why not both?

Comment: @Hakase because only one is the final closure reason

Comment: I just close as "too little detail" if it's just an image dump with no additional information. If it passes that, I try Google reverse image search via Madara's method.

Comment: Killua's method is also good because some of these image dumps really aren't trivially searchable, but for some reason that doesn't make the question any less trivial (e.g. it's a manga page, and Google counts all pages from all manga as similar images; it's a gif, and no one has found the one frame that's trivially reverse-searchable).

Comment: I was one of the people who had gotten this wrong.  I reverse image searched an image, found something that looked like a match, and started the close vote.  However, the correct answer wasn't what I had found, and was in fact something not easily found by reverse image search.  I'm not sure what to do in that kind of a case.