# Policy Clarification: Explicit & Borderline Content

Tags: discussion, policies

In order to make the site continue to run successfully, it's important all reviewers know the correct way to approach posts. As part of this, we had a [policy review](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/lets-take-a-look-back-at-our-site-policies-2015-edition) to see which were the policies that needed the most attention.The top voted policy to be reviewed was **Explicit & Borderline Content**. We will cover the other policies in the coming months.

[needs-clarification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needs-clarification)

> We've had a lot of run-in media on the site that would be considered
>   either explicit or borderline (even though they are hidden behind a
>   spoiler and/or have a NSFW warning). It's sometimes hard to tell if
>   the piece of media is explicit or not. A set of guidelines and set
>   procedures would probably help streamline things.
>
> Reason:
>
> Due to individual circumstances we're can't all agree on what's lewd
>   and not. In the fine art, there's a (fine) line between art and
>   pornography. Our personal upbringings shape how we think about these
>   things. We need to find some point where we can agree on at least.

As mentioned by @Torisuda, there are two cases to be clarified here:

1. Questions about works which contain explicit/borderline material.
2. Questions containing explicit/borderline content.

Please use this meta to help us concretely decide our community's policy on this.

Comment: With the first point are you referring to works like Kamuidori Alchemy Meister, Fate/Stay Night and Deardrops. particulary the last 2 which have seen non explicit versions/anime released of them or are you referring to echii themed anime/hentai

Comment: @Memor-X I'm not sure what's different about those series, but I mean ecchi/hentai anime as a whole.

Comment: all 3 are Visual Novels with Explicit content in the form of descriptions of sexual acts but said content is not the main purpose of the Visual Novels. with the last 2 they have both had all ages versions of them which have had the explicit content removed and both have had anime adaptions (Fate/Stay Night = multiple series, Deardrops = OVA), when you say "Questions about works which contain explicit/borderline material" Fate/Stay Night and Deardrops can be counted because in their original forms had explicit material.

Comment: (cont.) Kamidori is just the only Eushully Visual Novel i know of which is in english and doesn't have a weird premise (one such title the main character makes a contract with a goddess of fertility and the children he and the heroines have are used to fight in the game) but Eushully has the Battle Goddess Series which i assume has more plot than explicit content like Kamidori

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Sexually explicit content

**Sexually explicit content should be a no go as per site policy in both questions and answers. unless censored and answerable in a way that can comply with these policies and is handled [in a scientific way](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/are-adult-movies-as-far-as-industry-actors-etc-are-concerned-on-topic)**

Lets first define [site policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy), as this should be one of the main guidelines to adhere.

> *Sexually Explicit Material*. Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

Considering that what people might find offensive differs per culture, I suggest following the [IT law regarding sexually explicit content in connection with virtual worlds](http://itlaw.wikia.com/wiki/Sexually_explicit).

> [d]epictions or descriptions of: (1) sexual references; (2) full or partial nudity, including depictions of uncovered female breasts, aroused or unaroused male or female genitalia, and unrealistic or overly detailed genitalia; (3) bestiality; (4) sexual acts to or with minors (anyone under the age of 18); (5) sexual acts including, but not limited to, penetration/intercourse, and/or oral sex with or without another avatar or any other object, including overt sexual toys and/or sexual aids; or (6) sexual behavior that has a violent context." - [Summary List (TL;DR)](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/are-adult-movies-as-far-as-industry-actors-etc-are-concerned-on-topic)

There for explicit visual depictions should never be allowed, without proper censorship. Taken that hentai is in fact animated pornography, it is safe to say that hentai is off topic as per site policy, unless censored and answerable in a way to comply with these rules as well, [in a scientific way](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/are-adult-movies-as-far-as-industry-actors-etc-are-concerned-on-topic).

**Mild / borderline explicit content**

(1) sexual references, including (6) scarce clothing, which does not yet include partial nudity. Think of panty shots, skimpy clothing, naked bodys hidden by a cloud. Should be on topic, given that they are contained inside a >! (spoiler) area, and visibly warn the user of their content. This should both count for answers and questions alike. And were possible, especially in answers, avoided if possible.

### Graphic content (gore and violence)

**As there currently is no policy in place in regards to such graphics contents, and avoiding those in anime is nearly impossible. I suggest allowing this content, if properly hidden from direct few, with a visual disclaimer warning the user of its content, and if possible should be avoided. Especially in answers**

Currently there does not seem to be a rule regarding this on the site (correct me if I am wrong). There for I suggest the following:

Uncensored Graphic content such as, depicted murder, assault, suicides and or tortures. Or any other scenario leading to injury, bloody weapons, extensive blood effects or anything similar of nature. Should be contained in a >! (spoiler) area. and visibly warn the user of their contents.

Answers should try to avoid this content as much as possible, but in case this is not possible, adhere to the above mentioned rules as well.

Which I based upon [Graphical content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_violence) as mentioned on wikipedia.

Comment: Assume a question is asked about the [Sono Hanabira OVA](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11567) asking how it may be similar/different from the [Original Visual Novel](https://vndb.org/v925). to my recollection (need to double check my sources) the difference between the 2 is when Reo and Mai are intimate (ie. in the Visual Novel they are intimate when Reo is sick while in the OVA it is when Mai is sick). considering the OVA is Hentai and some can see the Visual Novel as hentai to in the same way the first Fate/Stay Night would such a question be on/off-topic

Comment: @Memor-X Such questions can be on-topic, if 1) the question is formated in a scientific way and 2) the answer can be phrased in a scientific way, and in both cases, if reference to the explicit series is required, clear visual notice should be given in regards to the potential unsuited content, and graphical content should be avoided at all cost.   TL:DR: Assuming that both can be phrased in a scientific way, this is on topic

Comment: To put it simply, this means that asking non-explicit content from explicit series is okay, as long as there's a notice as precaution that the series is explicit? (Refer to questions like [tag:mnemosyne])

Comment: @AkiTanaka Yes. that is correct. Where Mild / borderline explicit content is a exception, if handled properly