# When should a cosplay be tagged as Identification request

Tags: discussion

[Taking a look at this revision history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/27208/revisions) I noticed a lot of adding and removing of the [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag.

The tag itself clearly states

**Do**

- When identifying a anime/manga
- When identifying a character

**Don't s**

- Music Identification.

Seeing as most people are trying to identify a series/character when asking about cosplay, shouldn't they be tagged as [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) as well?

Or should they be handled as [Image only identification requests](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/image-only-id-request-cleanup?cb=1) and closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identifying a cosplay character should be tagged as [cosplay](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosplay) based on the changes we made to [image only id requests.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/image-only-id-request-cleanup?cb=1)

> Cosplay based questions should use the cosplay tag.
>
> Note that these execeptions will need to comply with general identification standards of providing additional information - such as venue, place of purchase, markings, et cetera.

Image only id-requests were removed because of their lack of context and detail.

We have made an experimental exclusion for certain topics such as cosplay **provided the questions contain additional detail.**

Such details for cosplay can be:

- A certain cosplayer
- Name of the convention + date
- Stall / Store selling the outfit
- As part of a stage play
- etc.

**TL;DR:** Cosplay identification questions should only be tagged as [cosplay](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosplay) but must meet the general minimum standard of detail to be kept on-topic.