# Are questions that ask to identify anime-related items also off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, identification-questions

Are questions that ask to identify anime-related items also off-topic?

For example, a question like:

> I bought this figure on eBay. [photo] From which anime is it?

I have seen quite a few of these on the site that are still open, so I wondered whether the site is still in the process of removing them or if these are considered on-topic.

An example: [What anime are these figures from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/32243/what-anime-are-these-figures-from)

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe they are. Originally, these questions fell under the Image-Only ID Request group. However, before making id requests off-topic and black listing the tag, we did try and improve the quality of incoming id requests by making image-only id requests off-topic.

In [this meta discussion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2726/1587) which outlined the accepted policy for dealing with image only id requests, Merchandise and Cosplay questions were considered an acceptable subset which we would want to keep:

> That is why I would like to limit these questions to a specific subset. (Feel free to suggest additions in the comments):
>
> - Merchandise
> - Cosplay from a convention you attended
>
> My rationale for these exemptions is that they provide more information for our answerers - With merchandise, the user can provide any angles requested, any markings on the items, place of purchase, etc. Cosplay can also aid identification through offical convention media such as facebook groups, titled photo galleries & cosplayers often advertise their personal pages. Note that this does not include random cosplays from the internet (although perhaps this rule could be relaxed based on feedback from the rest of the users here).

Because these 2 subsets have their own tags [merchandise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchandise) and [cosplay](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosplay) and these tags still remain and not blacklisted, I do believe that we still accept id requests on cosplay and merchandise.