# Are questions regarding cosplay or anime-related items still on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, identification-questions

Just recently [this question got closed](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/44312/2869). However, based on [this answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3846/2869), they're still on topic.

> In this meta discussion which outlined the accepted policy for dealing with image only id requests, Merchandise and Cosplay questions were considered an acceptable subset which we would want to keep

Most of question with [cosplay](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosplay), [merchandise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchandise), or [itasha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itasha) tag are identification request but they're still not historically locked like any other identification question we originally had.

But I have to admit those are not a good questions.

Are we going to put another effort to make a guidelines to quality control (QC) those question like we used to do (I know you guys hate it but I think I'd ask it just to be sure). Or we just blindly accept/reject those questions?

Additionally, quoting [this meta question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2812/2869)

> Inform new users about the merchandise, cosplay, and itasha tags as needed. There will be a separate meta (to be updated) on guidelines of how to use these tags.

What should be used for the tag excerpt? As for now, nothing is mentioned in those tag excerpt on this matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMO for such questions, the OP should demonstrate why they believe the cosplay, merchandise, or *itasha* that needs to be identified is, in fact, anime or manga related. Simply posting a picture and saying "I found this" and asking "what is this" should not be adequate.

Even if the OP mistakes LoL cosplay for anime cosplay, if they are uninformed and assumed it to be anime as they say it in an anime section at a local comic convention and **explained the circumstances of why they thought it was anime/manga related**, I think they should be fine even if the answer is its not anime but it us from X franchise. If they explain the context and why they are asking, I think we should give them a chance. Most casual fans can't really tell what's from anime and what's just anime-like IMO.

These tags have definite artefacts to work off of. They are not necessarily easily reversed image searched as they are not directly from visual media, so IMO they are worthwhile questions to answer.

Comment: so in short, they're on topic?

Comment: I would consider them so if they follow said guideline demonstrating effort made, for the time being.