# Can I ask about the anime or manga characters on a movie character’s t-shirt?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, acceptable-questions

I am posting this following the advice from the FAQ meta post, "[What identification requests are acceptable here? Otherwise, where else can I possibly get helped with it?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4190/310)"

In the movie *[No Hard Feelings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Hard_Feelings_(2023_film))*, one of the main characters, Percy, wears a t-shirt with two anime or manga characters on it. I have screenshots of the scenes where the characters are visible on his t-shirt. I would like to know who they are and what anime or manga they come from. I tried using Google Images, but to no avail, so I wonder if I can ask here. (I'm getting anime/manga results, but the results seem to be the wrong anime/manga.)

According to the above meta post:

> Anime & Manga Stack Exchange still accepts some kinds of identification requests, *particularly if the series is known*:
>
> […]
> 3. Cosplay/merchandise/*itasha*, [but with some exceptions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4142/are-questions-regarding-cosplay-or-anime-related-items-still-on-topic)

Does the t-shirt qualify as merchandise according to the [above meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4190/310)? Is this a valid question for this site?

Comment: For history and data, based on a quick search, I found 3 existing questions ([1](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/8073/2516), [2](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/37912/2516), [3](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20776/2516)) ordered by their quality, all downvoted and already deleted. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aNLV.jpg) mentioned the source (Uniqlo), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSYqo.jpg) didn't mention the source and got closed as ID-req, although someone argued that it shouldn't be closed in the first place, and [3](https://i.imgur.com/hUy0J9I.png) was self-deleted.

Comment: Probably that's also why my first impression was that the [tag:merchandise] tag is *not* for identifying clothing merchandise because I've never seen them, and I thought it might fall into image identification before doing the search. But now I *think* that it might be on-topic, but has a high bar similar to other ID-req. Note that I'm not taking a position yet, thus this is not posted as an answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all anime styled designs are from. An anime. Sometimes it's a specially commissioned piece for the production, if it's not some sort of product placement, to avoid copyright and licensing issues.

Comment: @кяαzєя That's true. It is possible that the answer would be “no, that’s not from an anime/manga”, but I won’t find out for sure unless I ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask it under the merchandise tag, but there is that caveat that as fans, we can't definitive say yes or no, here as we're not privy to things that went on in the production. Of course there are ways to reach out to staff on the production, but unless you have an in, in terms of connections, and know who to ask, the question will likely be stuck in limbo. Answers should be supported by sources, for such a question it's unlikely to find even a tertiary source on it.

We don't typically get questions about clothing and when we do it's usually about identifying where something like a print comes from. When you see a T-shirt one would assume that you can get one somewhere. As printed T-shirts are typically considered merchandise you can buy. If there is a need/demand, for a tag identifying specific props from a movie of tv series, we can consider it but it needs to be specialized. For an example do we limit it anime/manga related placement in a RL series/movie?