# Would questions asking for scene that can illustrate a concept on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, identification-questions, acceptable-questions

From [What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [all identification questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2725/4663) or recommendation requests are off-topic. However I'm not sure if asking for a scene in a particular anime/manga is off-topic or not.

Here is my question:

> #### Is there any scene in Dragon Ball that's about helping a rival to their maximum potential before taking them down (steelman argument)?
>
> The "steelman argument" or "[Rapoport's rules](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Rapoport%27s_Rules)" is a protocol to compose a successful (and helpful) critical commentary:
>
> 1. You should attempt to re-express your target's position so clearly, vividly, and fairly that your target says, "Thanks, I wish I’d thought of putting it that way."
> 2. You should list any points of agreement (especially if they are not matters of general or widespread agreement).
> 3. You should mention anything you have learned from your target.
> 4. Only then are you permitted to say so much as a word of rebuttal or criticism.
>
> [I heard that](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/109575/is-there-any-movie-scene-about-helping-a-rival-to-their-maximum-potential-before?noredirect=1#comment186257_109575) half of the scene in Dragon Ball is about this concept. Can you help me?
>
> **Note:** it's not just simply waiting for the opponent to heal themselves, but actively helping them reach their the best form and then argue/fight with this.

I wonder whether the question is still fine if instead of just one anime/mange, I provide a list of anime/mange?

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder whether the question is still fine if instead of just one anime/mange, I provide a list of anime/mange?`

Given the questions current phrasing, I would say no, it would not be on-topic.

The question would likely become too broad, and not meet the criteria required for a list question anymore.

The policy regarding this can be found over here [What is the status of list questions on this site?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/348/1458), but for convenience I have included them below as well

- The list criteria is specific and to the point.
- The list criteria is not asking about a list of abstract concepts or anime series featuring some theme.
- The list items can be determined objectively, without need for opinion.
- The list is reasonably scoped.
- The list isn't prone to rapid change.

Comment: @Ooker Additionally you may want to elaborate a bit on what you would like to use this data/information for. Perhaps I/we can assist in making it a fitting question for A&M

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the question could work if you elected to narrow the scope a bit more.

As opposed to looking for *any* scene in Dragon Ball, it'd be first worth...

- ...specifying which franchise you're referring to (e.g. Dragon Ball, Dragon Ball Z, Dragon Ball GT, etc).
- ...specifying which arc within that franchise you're referring to (and you get DBZ arcs since that's all I remember!) (e.g. Frieza arc, Cell arc, Buu arc, etc).

But most importantly...be willing to accept different perspectives and that your exact and precise answer may not be applicable.  That is to say, if I were to answer your question today as written, using a specific arc as an example, I would consider what's going on a bastardized Steelman argument as opposed to a full-fledged Steelman argument.